# Какую книгу посоветуете для изучения c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброе время суток, посоветуйте книгу по изучению c# wpf с нуля...
так же интересует c# с нуля, какая книга лучше для новичка.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Любую из списка в разделе для WPF. А дальше практика практика и практика.

Comment: Но, к слову, C# не единственный язык программирования для .NET. Есть еще и другие - F#, VB.NET (список можно продолжать) на них тоже можно писать WPF приложения.

Answer (score 3):

> **WPF 4. Подробное руководство** Адам Натан

Answer (score 1):

Имеется перечень книг предлагаемых для изучения, они все предложены [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0).

Answer (score 0):

Сам учился по книге "Изучаем C#". Авторы Эндрю Стиллмен, Дженнифер Грин. Там и про особенности языка и про wpf. Довольно всё доходчиво и в лёгкой повествовательной форме, без тяжёлых, нагруженных конструкций более серьёзных учебников.

[Ссылка на озоне](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/7246392/)

Answer (score 0):

Лучший вариант - это примеры кода хорошего .net разработчика. Т.к. увиденное на примере куда лучше дней, а то и недель изучения. Посоветую базовый курс  (для совсем новичков) и курс для начинающих (это основная база), и курс для профессионалов вот этого человека:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0udrpe_gZE&t=47s

Поймешь все быстрее и в голове будет не каша, а правильное представление об ООП и возможностях .NET. Мое субъективное мнение.

Comment: Опасный совет. Практика дело хорошее, но без должной теории вы так и останетесь на среднем уровне. Проводя аналогию, вы можете хорошо водить машину, но не разбирясь в устройстве двигателя когда-нибудь заглохнете в пустыне и умрёте без помощи. Книги надо читать, примеры кода надо смотреть. Всё надо делать

Comment: Я дал ссылку для стартера, для человека, который хочет разобраться с нуля. Как раз-таки в его лекциях ничего не упущено, "отсебячины" нет и, по моему, лучшего для новичка я не встречал. Книги часто переводятся с английского и переводят иногда не совсем корректно, т.к. переводят не программисты, это нужно учесть. Научиться играть музыке тоже можно по книжке, это разное, но своего рода тоже кодирование, только в нотах. ))